# How do I interpret and troubleshoot occurances of Linux system errno?

Tags: linux, troubleshooting

In system administration and software development on Linux, it is very common to come across errors that come from the system C library and/or kernel, which I will call "errnos" (short for "Error Numbers") from now on.

Sometimes, the only concrete evidence we have to diagnose a problem comes from a few key words in an application stack trace describing an error. It can be extremely difficult to get more specific information in complex "system of systems" scenarios.

The problem is that many errnos are vague, and even going back to the POSIX standards that define them, their descriptions are cryptic at best. I understand these errors being loosely defined at the standards level, but within the context of modern Linux, many of these errnos should have very specific causes, failure modes, symptoms, and troubleshooting steps.

## Example of what I seek for `ENETUNREACH`

Based on my own knowledge, I'm going to give you a bit of a write-up about the errno #101, `ENETUNREACH`, whose `strerror()` is `Network Unreachable`. **I would like to find a reference that provides this level of detail about as many of the errnos as possible, with specific things to check for each one.**

---

I'm of the belief that Linux errno 101, `ENETUNREACH`, `Network Unreachable` occurs on Linux when:

- You're doing some kind of IP stack network call, like `send()` or `sendmsg()`.
- The system looks up the 'next-hop' to get to the destination in your route table, and finds none.

**Troubleshooting, failure modes and recommendations:**

- This basically can't occur if your destination is a valid IP (i.e., not in 169.254.0.0/16 or some other 'always unreachable' net) and if your system normally has a default route.
- So, if you know your destination is in, say, valid public IP space, and your system normally has a default route, you can conclude that at the time this call was made, the system did not have a default route. (The default route is a route with a destination of `0.0.0.0/0`, meaning "regardless of where you're trying to send the IP datagram, your next hop is `w.x.y.z`."
- **Why wouldn't I have a default route?!** -- The system would remove the default route if, say, the network interface that provided the default route were set to `DOWN` at the link layer, like if you ran `ifconfig eth0 down` or physically unplugged a network cable, or the virtual equivalent of that in cloud systems.
- **Helping you narrow down the problem, it isn't the endpoint!** Assuming your box normally has a default route, and you're trying to reach a valid IP, `ENETUNREACH` has absolutely nothing to do with whether the endpoint is actually reachable, since the core of the problem is that your own system can't figure out how to get there from its route table.
- So the remote endpoint could be perfectly fine, or it could be down, and you could receive `ENETUNREACH` in both cases.

All of that troubleshooting is incredibly useful info that's "in my head" (and I'm not even 100.0% positive it's correct), but I don't have a source that substantiates it.

I've looked in POSIX.1-2001 (also known as SUSv3), which is what `man errno` leads me to;  this standard cryptically says:

> No route to the network is present.

OK, great. But my colleagues aren't going to know how to convert *that* information into solid deductions about what to look for when you see this in an application log.

---

**To be clear,** I am not looking for *only* information about `ENETUNREACH`. I'm ideally looking for a detailed analysis of failure modes and causes for *each* errno, or at least, the most common ones. Connection Refused, Connection Timed Out, Network Unreachable, Destination Host Unreachable, Permission Denied, No Space Left on Device, etc.

I view this as *essential* information for anyone operating in my field (cloud operations, almost exclusively using Linux virtual servers with very complex systems of systems), but the only thing I can find is "you have to learn what these mean through experience as a trick of the trade".

I also have heard comments like "Read the source code of the Linux kernel and glibc to get a full picture" but that *also* isn't helpful to a cloud operator.

Is there a better way to look up the causes and potential solutions for these error numbers for a cloud operator?

Comment: Requests for learning materials (tutorials, how-tos etc.) are off topic. The only exception is questions about where to find official documentation (e.g. POSIX specifications). See the Help Center and our Community Meta for more information.

Comment: A system or library call defines its return values, but I know of nothing like an inverted index (except Google, etc.) that lists all the library and system calls by return value. There is [`man 3 errno`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) for Linux-based systems and [`man 2 errno`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=errno&sektion=2&manpath=freebsd-release-ports) for FreeBSD, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @roaima Thanks; I've seen the manpages and they don't provide enough detail. Also, even the documentation for individual syscalls like `send()` and `sendmsg()` have extremely cryptic descriptions of the semantics of when a given errno will be thrown, and what that means for the state of the system. Successful diagnosis based solely on errno strings has been a hallmark of my career as a valued troubleshooter of all system maladies wacky and wild, but I don't know how to capture that for others. Maybe I need to write a book!

Comment: for the example from OP: Network is unreachable can be received by a perfectly fine system correctly configured: any router in the path to the destination can send back this error using the out of band channel meant for this: ICMP packet. The ICMP Destination network unreachable will translate into the application getting an ENETUNREACH.